# TypeScript type dependent on property name?

Tags: typescript

This is a bit of a strange question, but I still got curious of it's possible.

I have a JSON structure from an API that defines a map like this:

```
"sizes: {
    "thumbnail": "xxxx",
    "thumbnail-width: 150,
    "thumbnail-height: 150,
    "medium: "xxx",
    "medium-width": 500,
    "medium-height": 500,
    ...
}
```

The names is somewhat predefined, but not really.

My question is if it's possible to define any property that ends with -width or -height to number and everything else as string. Like a regex (.*)-(width|height): number.

TypeScript can do all kind of magic stuff, but can it do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, as of TS4.1, there is no specific, concrete type in TypeScript (let's call it `Values`) which represents the values assignable to that `values` property.  For the record, I'm interpreting this as: any string key is acceptable; if the key ends with `-width` or `-height`, the property must be a `number`; otherwise it must be a `string`.  There is no requirement that such keys must show up as triplets; for example, if `"key"` is a key, then it is not required that `"key-height"` or `"key-width"` be present.

Perhaps when [microsoft/TypeScript#42192](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42192) gets addressed you'll be able to use "pattern" template literals (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) of the form `` `${string}-width` `` as keys.  For now you cannot.

**UPDATE for TS4.4:** even with pattern template literal index signatures as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44512](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44512), you can't make a specific type for `Values`.  You can now represent the part where arbitrary strings ending in `-height` or `-width` must be `number`:

```
type NumericValues = {
  [key: `${string}-${"height" | "width"}`]: number; 
}
```

but there's no way to represent the "everything else needs to be a `string`" constraint... see [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  So the following doesn't work:

```
type BadValues = {
  [key: `${string}-${"height" | "width"}`]: number; // error! incompatible
  [key: `${string}`]: string; // can't say "everything else" here
}
```

Oh well.

---

So you can only represent your restriction as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), of the form `Values<K>` for an appropriate `K`:

```
type Values<K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: P extends `${string}-${"height" | "width"}` ? number : string
};
```

If `K` is the set of string-valued keys in `Values<K>`, then each property value must be either a `number` or a `string` depending on whether or not `K` ends in `"-height"`/`"-width"`.

Instead of being forced to annotate a value as type `Values<K>` for some concrete `K`, you could use a helper function to make the compiler infer `K` for you:

```
const asValues = <K extends string>(values: Values<K>) => values;
```

Let's try it:

```
const sizes = asValues({
  "thumbnail": "xxxx",
  "thumbnail-width": 150,
  "thumbnail-height": 150,
  "medium": "xxx",
  "medium-width": 500,
  "medium-height": 500,
}); // okay

const badSizes = asValues({
  "toenail": 123, // error! Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
  "toenail-width": 456,
  "psychic": "yyy",
  "psychic-height": "tall" // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
})
```

Looks good. `sizes` is accepted, but `badSizes` results in errors on the properties whose types are incorrect.

---

Of course the fact that we're using generics means that you have to drag around the generic type parameter `K` everywhere you want to enforce this restriction.  This could become unwieldy if used for your whole code base.  Instead you might want to just use `Values<K>` to validate object literals passed-in, and then when you manipulate them you widen to the closest specific type that TypeScript can represent, like a [`string`-indexable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) type whose properties are `string | number`:

```
type WideValues = { [k: string]: string | number };
const wideValues: WideValues = sizes; // okay
```

So you use `Values<K>` for validation, and `WideValues` for manipulation afterward.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210622#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgEwGpwDYFcIGcoF4oDeAUFFANoDWEIAXFAAYAkBWwATgJYB2A5gL4BaZgCIAFhA49RwYVAA+UYQHcOCYKOF96AXTpd0AWwBGENgG4oAektRTbAPZsAhFG4BjewbBxgHI6ggScipaBmZWTl4tXSgI7h4LaygueyglOBAoYFSsDMU43hx1HygEVJTgWy4ENI51KAFxSWkoRwaVNQ0iPiIiUEgoFAxsAB4AaVsAD2AIapwCngA+PEIgsgAFVy4oMZjNiGnZhBwmFnZ4wREmqRl5RQ71TXooAH5kwxM2KDoF7rNejxcVhQOBYIaYHD4cZTGZzWLnXiLAAUADc0BC6ODRmNFgBKPDLNHDLD-IiA4FYDgAL2wK1BWKwSOIpGE6g+XDgHFQwjowkm-MmwgANEFWaJ2ZzUAIHho6ABGACsAAYRSy2cYOVzGhIbjyoIqVaKDBAEBxDHq+fzhUaTWaDNLVI86MrDSzjabDNrmjJnUrDXxcYkbPYKBkAfYgZUjIgAMrU2n4eno7BM0XZWaSvVygBMAGYhVYbHZHC4ACrgaAAcn0xlMldcOAqIKwlJ4HP80GyWQrUErC0rafsGa1Mr1ABYFQA2VWKMBYEBuUQcNwWkBr60sucLpduL263nANDcwtQcsDPsInj1jiN+yVUGt9sBLKpfpVmufAcB3pvqAAdVUCAGRWAhgh+S8YgWO4P1MKA+H+clKg6IDkywOgAIQFDiRWSkaRJE8QwyIA)

Answer (score 1):

From typescript 4.1 it is possible, using literal types.
An example:

```
type AddSuffixToEachProps<T, Suffix extends string, Value extends any> = T & {
    [P in keyof T as `${string & P}-${Suffix}`]: Value
}
```

This is a type that accept some sort of schema, and add a suffix for each of those props.

Usage:

```
type Result = AddSuffixToEachProps<{
    foo: string,
    bar: string[]
}, 'width', number>

const test: Result = {
    foo: 'some string',
    "foo-width": 123, // required
    bar: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    "bar-width": 456 // required
}
```

Comment: This works if the prefixes are known in advance but the question implies that they are not (or “not really” in any case).

Comment: Kind of thought `Record<`${string}-width` | `${string}-height`, number>` would have worked, but it doesn't.

Comment: Very cool, but only works if the keys are known at compile time, and in that case I could as well define the width and height property.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Because

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

We can't set type `${string}-width` or `${string}-height` as a key type of `sizes`.

Comment: Don't think that explains it as ``type T = {[x in `${string}-width` | `${string}-height`]: number}`` compiles just fine, but somehow resolves to `T = {}`, which seems buggy to me.

Comment: Yes, seems buggy to me too. I think this feature is not fully supported yet.

Comment: Yeah, it's a known issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#42192](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42192)